# Too Many Arguments to function 'int mkdir(const char*)'

Tags: c, mingw

I am trying to compile a linux written program under windows (I use mingw)

```
void make_directory(const char* name) {
  mkdir(name1, name2);
}
```

There is an error:

```
Too Many Arguments to function 'int mkdir(const char*)'
```

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: `mkdir` function takes only an argument, but you are passing two or you are passing incompatible data types.

Comment: please consider add the `C` tag. And if the mkdir() here is part of some API, the library/API name and your environment, e.g, linux/POSIX etc.

Answer (score 9):

As said in the comments, `mkdir()` takes only **one** argument. However since this function is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235326.aspx) you should [use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw.aspx) `_mkdir()` instead:

```
int _mkdir(const char *dirname); 
int _wmkdir(const wchar_t *dirname); /* for wide-character */
```

If you want your function on both systems (linux / mingw):

```
void make_directory(const char* name)
{
#ifdef __linux__
    mkdir(name, 777); /* Or what parameter you need here ... */
#else
    _mkdir(name);
#endif
}
```

---

**Edit:**

*MinGW implementation:*

**_mkdir():**

```
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _mkdir (const char*);
```

**mkdir():**

```
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW mkdir (const char*);
```

Both are specified in `io.h`, but i guess its better to include `direct.h` instead (includes `io.h` in its part).

Comment: `mkdir()` is a POSIX standard function. It's deprecated *by Microsoft*; I'm not sure how seriously Microsoft's opinion on this matter should be taken.

Comment: And the POSIX `mkdir()` function actually takes *two* arguments; see my answer for details.

Comment: The POSIX one, yes. But the MinGW implementation (see edit of my post) takes only one. For this reason you should differ Windows (MinGW) / linux - whatever function you choose.

Comment: And as I understand it MinGW simply uses Microsoft's runtime library, so it's really the Microsoft `mkdir()` that takes a single argument. It's a great pity that Microsoft and POSIX have incompatible functions with the same name, but the history of both goes back far enough (to early UNIX and MS-DOS, respectively) that it's not too surprising. So Microsoft is deprecating *its own* `mkdir()` function, and that's probably a good thing given the name conflict. (I'll withhold my opinion on choosing `_mkdir()` for the new name.)

Comment: Exactly, MinGw is "GCC for Windows". OS functions like this one are from C runtime library (`_CRTIMP`).

Comment: Shouldn't "777" be "0777". I don't have much experience, but was under the assumption permissions was a bitmask specified with an octal value.

Answer (score 9):

I managed to get away with this, for a Linux written program building under mingw-w64:

```
#if (defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__))
#define mkdir(A, B) mkdir(A)
#endif
```

Comment: I had to add the include in the if/endif for MinGW lib: 
```#include <direct.h> /* _mkdir */``` and use _mkdir instead of mkdir

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume that `name1` and `name2` are both names of directories you want to create (but see below).

`mkdir()` creates (or attempts to create) a single directory. If you want to create two directories, you need to call `mkdir()` twice.

And just to add to the confusion, the POSIX `mkdir()` function actually takes *two* arguments -- but the second argument is not a name. Quoting the man page on my system:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int mkdir(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
```

The `_mkdir()` function mentioned in ollo's answer is specific to Microsoft Windows, and it takes a single argument; modes, i.e. permissions, work differently on Windows than they do on POSIX (Unix, Linux, et al) systems.

But your compiler obviously thinks that `mkdir()` takes only one argument, which makes wonder why it thinks so. What header did you `#include` to get the declaration of the `mkdir` function?

As I mentioned above, the POSIX `mkdir()` takes two arguments, but the second is a `mode_t`, not a name. You say the code was originally written for Linux. Are the arguments really called `name1` and `name2`, or did you try to simplify the code by changing the names? Can you update the question to show us the actual copy-and-pasted code?

Comment: The OP hasn't been seen on stackoverflow since August 2012, so it's likely we won't see any updates to the question.

Comment: I know, but maybe it helps someone else.

Comment: Btw. interesting post, +1 for that.